# Replacing dates in a character vector to a specific format

Tags: r

I am given the following character vector:

```
"On the evening of 2017-04-23, I was too tired"
"to complete my homework that was due on 24.04.2017."
```

I need to search through it for all occurrences of dates and replace them with the format Monthname D, YYYY.

I know the general format should be %B %d, %Y and that I probably have to use the `sub()` function but I am not quite sure how to bring the two together.

When I try something like

```
sub("[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}","%B %d, %Y",x)
```

I just get the following result

```
"On the evening of 2001-01-15, I was too tired to complete my homework that was due on %B %d, %Y."
```

Could someone please help me figure out how to bring it all together?

---

My new code with the help of fellow stackoverflowers is as follows:

```
streamlineDates(x)
{
#set pattern to dates in form of YYYY-MM-DD or DD.MM.YYYY
pattern <- "\\d{2,4}[.-]\\d{2}[.-]\\d{2,4}"

y <- c(x)

val <- unlist(regmatches(y, gregexpr(pattern, y)))

val1 <- as.Date(val,format=c("%Y-%m-%d","%d.%m.%Y"))
val2 <- format(val1,"%B %d, %Y")

y1 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(y)){
  y1[i] <- gsub(pattern,val2[i],y[i])
}
}
```

However, when I input only:

```
x <- "to complete my homework that was due on 24.04.2017."
```

...it only return NA. I have narrowed the issue down to `gsub` where the *replacement* value, **"if NA, all elements in the result corresponding to matches will be set to NA"**. So as the first date is missing when only the last line is input, it returns only NA.

How can I make it accept either or both dates?

Comment: the data format (e.g. `%B %d %Y`) cannot be used in the `sub` or `gsub` functions, it has to be used in `as.Date`

Comment: @sooki-sooki see my solution, I hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st Method:**

Using **BASE R** solution(Without using any package):

```
pattern <- "\\d{2,4}[.-]\\d{2}[.-]\\d{2,4}"
rep <- c("On the evening of 2017-04-23, I was too tired","to complete my homework that was due on 24.04.2017.")


val <- unlist(regmatches(rep, gregexpr(pattern, rep)))

val1 <- as.Date(val,format=c("%Y-%m-%d","%d.%m.%Y"))
val2 <- format(val1,"%B %d, %Y")
val2
rep1 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(rep)){
rep1[i] <- gsub(pattern,val2[i],rep[i])
}
```

**Answer:**

```
do.call("c",rep1)

> do.call("c",rep1)                                                   
[1] "On the evening of April 23, 2017, I was too tired"      
[2] "to complete my homework that was due on April 24, 2017."
>
```

**2nd Method:**

Use library `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
rep <- c("On the evening of 2017-04-23, I was too tired","to complete my homework that was due on 24.04.2017.")
val <- str_extract(rep,"\\d{2,4}[.-]\\d{2}[.-]\\d{2,4}")
val1 <- as.Date(val,format=c("%Y-%m-%d","%d.%m.%Y"))
val2 <- format(val1,"%B %d, %Y")
rep1 <- str_replace_all(rep,"\\d{2,4}[.-]\\d{2}[.-]\\d{2,4}",val2)
rep1
```

**Answer:**

```
> rep1
[1] "On the evening of April 23, 2017, I was too tired"      
[2] "to complete my homework that was due on April 24, 2017."
>
```

**EDIT After OP has changed the question little bit, The solution is more generic, however it is assumed that month will always be in middle and the delimiters are only restricted to dash(-) and dot(.):**

```
pattern <- "\\d{2,4}[.-]\\d{2}[.-]\\d{2,4}"
rep <- c("On the evening of 2017-04-23, I was too tired","to complete my homework that was due on 24.04.2017.")


val <- unlist(regmatches(rep, gregexpr(pattern, rep)))

year <- regmatches(val, gregexpr("\\d{4}", val))

month <- regmatches(val, gregexpr("(?<=[.-])\\d{1,2}(?=[.-])", val,perl=T))

date <- regmatches(val, gregexpr("(?<=[.-])\\d{2}$|^\\d{2}(?=[.-])", val,perl=T))
#Extracting year month and date , assuming month always falls in middle string

date1 <- paste0(year,"-",month,"-",date)
date1 <- as.Date(date1,"%Y-%m-%d")
val2 <- format(date1,"%B %d, %Y")

rep1 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(rep)){
  rep1[i] <- gsub(pattern,val2[i],rep[i])
}


do.call("c",rep1)
```

Comment: This is great but would there be a way of doing so without any additional libraries i.e. just the standard pre-loaded R library?

Comment: I was just running some further tests on the code and noticed that if only "to complete my homework that was due on April 24, 2017." is given as input, the code doesn't work and just returns NA. 
Do you maybe know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Please understand, if you want to achieve the correct result for each and every scenario. you have to put the corresponding correct format on `as.Date(val,format=c("%Y-%m-%d","%d.%m.%Y"))` like here we have put two different format for two different date stamps.  One format can't be associated with each and every format of date you have.Give me some time I am trying to make it generic. I don't if it is possible but would sure attempt it.

Comment: @sooki-sooki Please see a more generic solution in the answer part. I am deleting the conversation above as it is too heavy according to SO rules.Request you to delete unnecessary comments from your side

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to specify all formats of your dates. Then convert to date, and use format to get your desired output, i.e.

```
#Note that I don't use any delimiter in the formatting simply because 
#I will use gsub to replace all except the numbers with '' from the string
v1 <- c('%Y%m%d', '%d%m%Y')

format(as.Date(gsub('\\D+', '', x), format = v1), "%B %d, %Y")
#[1] "April 23, 2017" "April 24, 2017"
```

You can use (a rather ugly) regex with `str_replace_all` from `stringr` package, i.e.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(x, '\\d+-\\d+-\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+', 
                         format(as.Date(gsub('\\D+', '', x), format = v1), "%B %d, %Y"))

#[1] "On the evening of April 23, 2017, I was too tired"      
#[2] "to complete my homework that was due on April 24, 2017."
```