# Formatting and Replacing Multiple Dates within a Single String in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have a question very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256971/replacing-dates-in-a-character-vector-to-a-specific-format). The difference with mine is that I can have text with multiple dates within one string. All the dates are in the same format, as demonstrated below

```
rep <- "on the evening of june 11 2022, i was too tired to complete my homework that was due on august 4 2022. on august 25 2022 there will be a test "
```

All my sentences are lower case and all dates follow the  `%B %d %Y` format. I'm able to extract all the dates using the following code:

```
> pattern <-  paste(month.name, "[:digit:]{1,2}", "[:digit:]{4}", collapse = "|") %>% 
     regex(ignore_case = TRUE)
> str_extract_all(rep, pattern)
[[1]]
[1] "june 11 2022"   "august 4 2022"  "august 25 2022"
```

what I want to do is replace every instance of a date formatted  `%B %d %Y` with the format `%Y-%m-%d`. I've tried something like this:

```
str_replace_all(rep, pattern, as.character(as.Date(str_extract_all(rep, pattern),format = "%B %d %Y")))
```

Which throws the error `do not know how to convert 'str_extract_all' to class "Date"`. This makes sense to me since Im trying to replace multiple different dates and R doesn't know which one to replace it with.

If I change the `str_extract_all` to just `str_extract` I get this:

```
"on the evening of 2022-06-11, i was too tired to complete my homework that was due on 2022-06-11. on 2022-06-11 there will be a test "
```

Which again, makes sense since the str_extract is taking the first instance of a date, converting the format, and applying that same date across all instances of a date.

I would prefer if the solution used the `stringr` package just because most of my string tidying thus far has been using that package, BUT I am 100% open to any solution that gets the job done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may capture the pattern i.e one or more character (`\\w+`) followed by a space then one or two digits (`\\d{1,2}`), followed by space and then four digits (`\\d{4}`) as a group (`(...)`) and in the replacement pass a function to convert the captured group to `Date` class

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(rep, "(\\w+ \\d{1,2} \\d{4})", function(x) as.Date(x, "%b %d %Y"))
```

-output

```
[1] "on the evening of 2022-06-11, i was too tired to complete my homework that was due on 2022-08-04. on 2022-08-25 there will be a test "
```

NOTE: It is better to name objects with different names as `rep` is a `base R` function name

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a named vector with multiple replacements to `str_replace_all()`:

```r
library(stringr)

rep <- "on the evening of june 11 2022, i was too tired to complete my homework that was due on august 4 2022. on august 25 2022 there will be a test "
pattern <-  paste(month.name, "[:digit:]{1,2}", "[:digit:]{4}", collapse = "|") %>% 
  regex(ignore_case = TRUE)
extracted <- str_extract_all(rep, pattern)[[1]]
replacements <- setNames(as.character(as.Date(extracted, format = "%B %d %Y")), 
                     extracted)
str_replace_all(rep, replacements)
#> [1] "on the evening of 2022-06-11, i was too tired to complete my homework that was due on 2022-08-04. on 2022-08-25 there will be a test "
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>